# Python | traverse every element from a list in another for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

Want to traverse each element from below list one by one in next for loops.

How should i do it? how can i fit in one more for loop in it.

currently i am calling accessing **summaryList[1]** only one element

```
summaryList=['hi','bye','hello']

def list(path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, summaryList[1] + '.txt'):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable or function name, it's a built-in type name.

Comment: Under `for name in files:` just add `for summary in summaryList:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any()`:

```
if any(fnmatch(name, prefix+'.txt') for prefix in summaryList):
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well. so this will return the list which again i need to call one by one elements in with open(result[0],'r') as file. how can i do it ?

Comment: Return `result` from the function, then you can do `for file in value:` and open each of them.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this
`if os.path.splitext(name)[0] in summaryList:`
should work, fnmatch here seems not very usefull

Comment: Maybe the real `summaryList` can contain wildcards, and this is just a simplified example.

Comment: yes this was just a example list. actually it's a long list @Barmar

Comment: @pkk The length isn't an issue. Are they all just fixed strings, or do they contain wildcards that require using `fnmatch()`?

Comment: no no wildcards fixed strings